# Convert yolov4-tiny to transflow lite: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 374698 into shape (256,256,3,3)

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, yolov4

As I try to covert my yolov4-tiny custom weight to tftile, it always happen.

This is what I input:

```
python save_model.py --weights ./data/yolov4-tiny-obj-food_final.weights --output ./checkpoints/yolov4-tiny-416-tflite --input_size 416 --model yolov4 --framework tflite
```

And the wrong message appear.

```
conv_weights = conv_weights.reshape(conv_shape).transpose([2, 3, 1, 0])
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 374698 into shape (256,256,3,3)
```

I have checked my labels.txt and there is no space or more lines.Also, I have changed the name in config.py.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks for help!

Attach part of my code, hope it helps.

Here is github:https://github.com/piggychu0w0/food-image-detection

.cfg:

```
[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=21
activation=linear

[yolo]
mask = 3,4,5
anchors = 10,14,  23,27,  37,58,  81,82,  135,169,  344,319
classes=2
num=6
jitter=.3
scale_x_y = 1.05
cls_normalizer=1.0
iou_normalizer=0.07
iou_loss=ciou
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=0
resize=1.5
nms_kind=greedynms
beta_nms=0.6
```

.names:

```
rice
toast
```

Comment: 374698  is 2×187349 and 187349 is a prime number. How did you even make an array with that shape?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure how I did it. I refer to this paper to complete the weight file. 
https://blog.csdn.net/qq_44166805/article/details/105876028
@NatthaphonHongcharoen

Comment: The only different is that I convert it to Yolo format directly in labelimg.

Comment: The problem is that, because it is not divisible by anything but 2 so you can't reshape it to anything other than something like (2, 187349) or (1, 374698)

Comment: BTW, include the code too not just the config since it's the `save_model.py` that is causing the error, nothing to do with .cfg or .names

Comment: I had refresh my github, and there is other file like save_model or others. Do you have any idea where mistakes might happen? @NatthaphonHongcharoen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

You have to add `--tiny` to the command. Which, from the command you gave in the question, will be.

```
python save_model.py --weights ./data/yolov4-tiny-obj-food_final.weights --output ./checkpoints/yolov4-tiny-416-tflite --input_size 416 --model yolov4 --framework tflite --tiny
```

## Long answer

You see, there's [this line](https://github.com/piggychu0w0/food-image-detection/blob/main/save_model.py#L10) that if you set it to `True` (by adding `--tiny`) it will make the `load_weights()` uses `layer_size = 21` [here](https://github.com/piggychu0w0/food-image-detection/blob/main/core/utils.py#L27) instead of `layer_size = 110` [here](https://github.com/piggychu0w0/food-image-detection/blob/main/core/utils.py#L34).

The problem here is that the weights you have and the `np.fromfile` command actually give you a big chunk of 1 dimensional array, in this particular file it's size is `(5882629,)`, and then you have to allocate those variable one by one to the layers.

So, when you create the big model instead of tiny. The tiny weighs file runs out of the variable at 49th layers, and hilariously with such a big prime number.